# can I mark gulp task as non runnable by the developer?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have the following gulp tasks:

```
gulp.task('build', [], function () {
        log('Building the optimized app');
        return gulp.src('').pipe(plug.notify({
            onLast: true,
            message: 'Code Deployed!'
        }));
    });

gulp.task('build-debug', function (callback) {
    log('Building the optimized app in debug mode');
    debug = true;
    runSequence('clean', ['build'], callback);
});
```

You can see that build-debug using build.
I want the developer will be able to run build-debug **only**, meaning build task won't be runnable unless it's being called from build-debug.

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly "non runnable" but you can always make it not do anything unless called from build-debug and it seems like you're already setting a flag when that is the case so if you change the build task like so:

```
gulp.task('build', [], function () {
    if (!debug) {
        log('The build task cannot be run on its own, use \'build-debug\' instead');

        return;
    }

    log('Building the optimized app');
    return gulp.src('').pipe(plug.notify({
        onLast: true,
        message: 'Code Deployed!'
    }));
});
```